# How to put this as a Configurable way

Tags: java

I have a class which i will include it in a existing jar (by using the jar update command jar uf )

So as you might now know that this class is not modifiable so i  want my settings in a configurable way .

I have defined all my production servers and development servers inside a HashMap .(I can use Set , but
 choosen HashMap for solving another issue becaz i was getting ip as 127.0.0.1 and want to gather IP using hostname )

This is my log4j.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
   <appender class="com.Log4JCustomAppender" name="CUSTAPPEN">
     <param value="includeDevMachiens" name="no" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param value="%m" name="ConversionPattern" />
      </layout>
      </appender>
   <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="CUSTAPPEN" />
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

As you can see that there is a Param name `includeDevMachiens` if its value is  `no` , then dont want to execute the message when 
ran from development servers and vice versa

This is my code from which a message will be executed .

```
private String includeDevMachienes ;

    public String getIncludeDevMachienes() {
        return includeDevMachienes;
    }

    public void setIncludeDevMachienes(String includeDevMachienes) {
        this.includeDevMachienes = includeDevMachienes;
    }

String  hostAddresss = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

String include  = getIncludeDevMachienes(); // yes or no 

how can i use yes or no value here ??

 //   right now the execute will be called for everything if the hostaddress value  is present in the map .

if(hostIPMap.containsValue(hostAddress))
{
execute(logMessage);
}
```

Comment: `if (include && hostIPMap.containsValue(hostAddress)) { execute(logMessage); }`  or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: cant use && here , because if include is false , cant execute for prod machienes also .

Answer (score 0):

```
if(hostIPMap.containsValue(hostAddress)) {
    //Check include is yes/no
    if("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(getIncludeDevMachines())){execute(logMessage);}

    //do rest of the stuffs related to host
}
```

Comment: so as per the logic it seems that i will be calling execute(logMessage) two times here .

Comment: @Kiran How will it be called twice? Yes, you would not need the local variable `include` if you are using `getIncludeDevMachines()` directly.

Comment: because the rest of the logic will also contain the execute method ( as i need to use that for prod machienes compulsarly . and devlopment machienes are configurable

Comment: @Kiran May be I am misunderstanding the question altogether, I thought `execute()` is only meant for dealing with `logMessage`? Morepver. `log4j` attributes will be fetched per environment, you would be using some `configuration` to get the value per environment. I do not see any problem in this approach if I am heading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `<param value="includeDevMachiens" name="no" />`, you can use  `<param name="includeDevMachiens" name="True"`
Fetch this value as 
`boolean include  = Boolean.parseBoolean(getIncludeDevMachienes()); // yes or no` 
and then do your operation based on this flag.